# Android: Application and Activity themes stop working after addition of AAR library to the project

Tags: android, android-theme

I defined a deafult theme for the entire app in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.my.app"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Everything worked as expected until I added new AAR library into the project. After this point my theme setting is ignored, whether I defined it in `Application` tag, or for each individual `Activity`.

Inside my app, I have just one instance of `styles.xml` (where AppTheme is defined) under `res/values` path. The AAR library, on the other hand, has the same theme defined in the following locations: `res/values/values.xml`, `res/values-land/values-land.xml`, `res/values-sw600dp-v13/values-sw600dp-v13.xml`.

So, I guess my question is how do I prevent from the theme from a library module overriding my own theme?

Comment: as a hack try changing name of theme and check if its overriding .

Comment: @Manohar, this worked as a workaround. Interestingly, once I changed the name of my theme, build failed and asked to add `tools:replace="android:theme"` into the manifest. So, it looks like a bug: when app's theme and lib's theme have the same names, manifest merger can't distinguish between them. I wonder if there is a valid use case for this approach. In any case, please post your workaround as an answer.

Comment: Good to know it worked , I will be posting the answer as you suggested for future readers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppTheme is common name used for theme  most probably the library is also using the same theme name , changing the name of your theme should fix the issue .

Alternatively you can also add `tools:replace="android:theme"` in manifest .

Comment: Clarification: just adding `tools:replace="android:theme"` to the manifest didn't resolve my problem. It's only after I had changed the name of my theme that this setting became relevant. This looks like a bug in the build toolchain.